# Webpack DefinePlugin doesn't define variable inside ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, service-worker

I'm using Webpack's `DefinePlugin` to define a variable inside my Service Worker like so

```js
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require("webpack");

// I tried sending a string as '"test"' with no luck aswell

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "API_URL": process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_URL
    })
]
```

```js
// My Service Worker
workbox.setConfig({
   debug: false,
 });
 
 workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);
 
 workbox.routing.registerRoute(
   /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
   workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
     cacheName: 'images',
     plugins: [
       new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
         maxEntries: 3,
         maxAgeSeconds: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 day
       }),
     ],
   }),
 );

console.log(API_URL);
// outputs: ReferenceError: API_URL is not defined
```

I'm not able to access my env variables inside my service worker, is this solution even viable ?

```js
// registerServiceWorker.js

/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log("ready")
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: How do you generate your SW?

Comment: using registerServiceWorker

Comment: Do you create your SW by hand or using some webpack plugin?

Comment: `registerServiceWorker.js` looks like code that registers a service worker that's located in your `service-worker.js` file. `registerServiceWorker.js` is not itself a service worker.

Comment: I know, didn't feel like it would be usefull to see my entire service-worker.js file but updated it now